# sed replace entire line at line number with a string that contains nested quotes

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to use `sed` to replace a certain line with my own string that has to contain some nested quotes because it will be read by another programme and itself executing commands.

`sed -i '63s/^.*$/mystring/' file.txt`

Where `63` is the line number, `^.*$` is selecting the entire line to replace, `mystring` is the replacement string and `file.txt` is the file to work on.

Say for example I want to make `mystring` `exec: echo 'echo "127.0.0.1 localhost" >> /etc/hosts"'` how am I supposed to go about that? I've tried escaping the quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can for example do the following:

```
sed -i.bak "63s|^.*$|$string|" file.txt
```

A wayis to fetch it from a file. Also, note double quotes in `sed` are necessary to have the variable expanded.
Finally, use another delimiter for `sed` and store `$string` in a variable. For example, `|`. This is because your `$string` contain slashes and make `sed` see a command like `sed "s/^.*$/something/blabla/"`, which is so many slashes.

Also, `-i.bak` creates a backup of `file.txt` --> `file.txt.bak`.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hel
lo
ooo
bye
$ cat b
exec: echo 'echo "127.0.0.1 localhost" >> /etc/hosts"'
$ string=$(cat b)

$ sed "3s|^.*$|$string|" a
hel
lo
exec: echo 'echo "127.0.0.1 localhost" >> /etc/hosts"'
bye
```

---

If you don't want to do variable assignment, then just escape the problematic characters in your replacement string. In this case, just double quotes `"`:

```
sed -i.bak "63s|^.*$|exec: echo 'echo \"127.0.0.1 localhost\" >> /etc/hosts\"'|" file.txt
                                      ^                    ^               ^
```

#### Test

```
$ sed "3s|^.*$|exec: echo 'echo \"127.0.0.1 localhost\" >> /etc/hosts\"'|" a
hel
lo
exec: echo 'echo "127.0.0.1 localhost" >> /etc/hosts"'
bye
```

Comment: I don't want to use variable assignment, I just want to splice in the entire command, is it not possible without having the command in another file?

Comment: Then just escape it: `sed -i.bak "63s|^.*$|exec: echo 'echo \"127.0.0.1 localhost\" >> /etc/hosts\"'|" file`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed & Bash):

```
cat <<\! >quoted-text.txt
exec: echo 'echo "127.0.0.1 localhost" >> /etc/hosts"'
!

sed $'63{r quoted-text.txt\nd}' file
```

Put the difficult line of text into a file and replace the required line by reading said file and deleting the original line.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this also,

```
sed -i "63s~.*~exec: echo \'echo \"127.0.0.1 localhost\" >> /etc/hosts\"\'~g" file
```

It just need escaping of quotes and a different sed delimiter.

***Example:**

```
$ sed "2s~.*~exec: echo \'echo \"127.0.0.1 localhost\" >> /etc/hosts\"\'~g" file
abc, xym krg plf, 763, bla
exec: echo 'echo "127.0.0.1 localhost" >> /etc/hosts"'
```